# Required tags (discussion, bug, etc.) duplicated?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

For some reason, when I try to add any of the discussion, bug, or status-bydesign tags to my questions here on meta, that tag is listed in the suggestions list *twice*. Then, once I choose one of them, my question is tagged twice (as can be seen by this very bug report).

Interestingly, this has allowed me to put up to 7 tags on this question (5 plus two duplicates)

P.S. - Perhaps this belongs on meta.meta.gamedev? :-P

Comment: Funnily enough they also have different counts on the right of the question. "bug x5" and "bug x3".

Comment: Yes, it seems that inside SE's database, it's conceptually 2 separate tags that happen to have the same name, and certain questions are associated with each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have removed the duplicate tags.